How to get list of columns of dataframe including empty cells using polars
I have polar dataframe
df = pl.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet')
first_column_name = df.columns[0]
first_column = df[first_column_name].to_list()

When I do this, It is ignoring empty cells of column.
Also While doing len(df) It is also ignoring empty rows.
Can we fix this.

first  use pandas to read the Excel file and then convert it to a polars DataFrame. polars is focused on high performance and handling large datasets efficiently. Excel files are typically not the format used for large-scale data processing, as they can be slower to read and write compared to CSV.
pd_df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet', dtype=str) 
    
df = pl.DataFrame(pd_df)
first_column_name = df.columns[0]

first_column = df[first_column_name].to_list()

by doing this you can ensure that empty cells and rows are preserved correctly.

This will work. Maybe worth noting that it is empty rows in Excel which Polars will ignore, not an empty cell in an otherwise full row., which seems reasonable in that no data is lost.

@user19077881 yup you are correct. polars will ignore the  entirely empty rows ,but it  will preserve rows that have at least one non-empty cell. but it ensures that there is no data loss.
